# Is it possible to find the email id of aws IAM user using boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam, amazon-ses

Is it possible to find the email ID of AWS IAM user using boto3?

Email is not an attribute of IAM user. I can add email addresses in SES but there is no way to match IAM user ID with SES email.

I need to create a Lambda function to send email to the users based on activity.

Comment: Whoever voted negatively ... would you explain what was the reason???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. As you point out, email address is not stored against an IAM user. Therefore, the information is not available to retrieve.

One option is to enforce a standard where each IAM User's username is actually an email address (eg `joe@example.com`). Failing that, you'll need to maintain a lookup somewhere between Username and Email Address. IAM does not support storing additional attributes against users.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to add the attributes to dynamodb and then retrieve it.

Comment: Could probably put the email address as a tag right?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Yes, new functionality was added to IAM in November 2018 that allows tags to be associated with IAM Users and Roles. See: [Simplify granting access to your AWS resources by using tags on AWS IAM users and roles | AWS Security Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/simplify-granting-access-to-your-aws-resources-by-using-tags-on-aws-iam-users-and-roles/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

**Step 1:** You can **register a domain** in SES and follow a standard of naming the IAM user with the first part of his mail id of the same domain which is registered.
**Step 2:** And when you are sending the mail, append it to the domain name in your program and you will be able to send it to the IAM user.